# JPA/Hibernate Join only one selected column

Tags: java, database, spring, hibernate, jpa

To the existing table through `@ManyToOne`

```
    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumns({
            @JoinColumn(name = "ID", referencedColumnName = "APPLICATION_ID", insertable = false, updatable = false),
            @JoinColumn(name = "VERSION", referencedColumnName = "APPLICATION_VERSION", insertable = false, updatable = false)
    })
    private ApplicationsBodies applicationsBodies;
```

I join another table.

But from the join table, I want to join only one column.

```
@Entity
@Table
public class ApplicationsBodies implements Serializable {

... 

@Column(name = "APPLICATION_ID")
private Long applicationId;

@Column(name = "APPLICATION_VERSION")
private Long applicationVersion;

//I want to attach only this column
@Lob
@Column(name = "BODY")
private String body;

@Column(name = "ACTIVE_STATE")
private Integer activeState;
```

How can this be implemented using JPA / Hibernate?

**UPDATE: Solution**

My problem was solved by `@Formula` annotation. Because When I refer to an entity only for the purpose of loading this one field, for me it has become the most optimal solution.

I deleted the field: `private ApplicationsBodies applicationsBodies`. And created a field: `private String body` with annotation `@Formula` with value - SQL query joining only one column.

Answer (score 0):

if you want to use join with JPA data, then I recommend to use JPL Query Language. So in your repository classes use as annotation :

```
@Query("select a.name from ApplicationsBodies a join a.applicationId d where d.id = :applicationVersion")
```

Comment: Thank you for your reply. I solved my problem in a slightly different way. The decision indicated in the update record.